# Swift - How to have NSSharingServicePicker pops in a specific button?

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I'm learning Swift and creating my first project for OS X. I would like to have the NSSharingServicePicker popover displayed over a button "shareButton" when the user pushed that button.

I create the NSSharingServicePicker object with this code:

```
var text = "Hello, world!"
var share = NSSharingServicePicker(items: [text])
```

Now, how I have to customise this code to display the popover?

```
share.showRelativeToRect(rect: NSRect, ofView: NSView, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge)
```

I tried this but it shows the popover in a wrong position and the console shows me an error.

```
let rect = shareButton.frame
let edge : NSRectEdge = NSRectEdge.MaxY
let view = shareButton

share.showRelativeToRect(rect, ofView: view, preferredEdge: edge)
```

*"NSSharingServicePicker showRelativeToRect: ofView: preferredEdge:] should not be called on mouseUp
Please configure the sender with -[NSControl sendActionOn:NSLeftMouseDownMask];"*

Comment: I jtbandes, thank you for your comment, now I edited the original post and I added this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of All, to get rid of the NSLeftMouseDownMask warning thing, change the behavior of the button when your app starts up.  Put this code within viewDidLoad(), for example.

```
youShareButton.sendAction(on: NSLeftMouseDownMask)
```

And this is what I did for displaying the picker view on the button

```
let shareItems = [aURL]
let sharingPicker:NSSharingServicePicker = NSSharingServicePicker.init(items: shareItems)

let sharingPicker:NSSharingServicePicker = NSSharingServicePicker.init(items: shareItems)
sharingPicker.show(relativeTo: yourShareButton.bounds, of: yourShareButton, preferredEdge: .minY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I resolved by replacing:

```
let rect = shareButton.frame
```

with

```
let rect = NSZeroRect
```